# Confusing NullPointer Exception in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I wonder if here is someone who can help me investigate a weird (at least for me ) behaviour of Spring. I am  actually implementing changes to my project. After launching my code I get a good old NullPointer Exception. But the problem is Spring does not specifies where this error occurs. I get only some weird info about `org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer` and `javaassist.proxy.ProxyFactory.CreateClass`.

The code is little bit complex to display here so i will provide you with my GitHub repo link: https://github.com/sajmon2325/Spring-Pet-Clinic.git

I have already initialized all my Sets like:

```
Set<Owner> owners  = new HashSet<>();
```

So there shouldn't be any uninitialized Sets.

Also I included validation inside my classes so I should have to have all NullPointer Exceptions handled.

**Owner Entity**

```
package guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner extends Person {

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private String telephone;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>();

    Some getters and setters

}
```

**Person Entity**

```
package guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**Repository for Owner**

```
package guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.repositories;

import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model.Owner;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface OwnerRepository extends CrudRepository<Owner, 
Long> {

    Owner findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

**Owner Service**

```
package guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.services;

import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model.Owner;


public interface OwnerService extends CrudService<Owner, Long> {

    Owner findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

...

```
@Service
@Profile("springdatajpa")
public class OwnerSDJpaService implements OwnerService {

    private final OwnerRepository ownerRepository;
    private final PetRepository petRepository;
    private final PetTypeRepository petTypeRepository;


    public OwnerSDJpaService(OwnerRepository ownerRepository, 
         PetRepository petRepository, PetTypeRepository 
          petTypeRepository) {
            this.ownerRepository = ownerRepository;
            this.petRepository = petRepository;
            this.petTypeRepository = petTypeRepository;
    }       


    @Override
    public Owner findByLastName(String lastName) {
            return ownerRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Owner> findAll() {
        Set<Owner> owners = new HashSet<>();
        ownerRepository.findAll().forEach(owners::add);

        return owners;
    }

    @Override
    public Owner findById(Long aLong) {
        return ownerRepository.findById(aLong).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Owner save(Owner object) {
        return ownerRepository.save(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Owner object) {
        ownerRepository.delete(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long aLong) {
        ownerRepository.deleteById(aLong);
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace but it is pretty long

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-02 22:27:38.143 ERROR 13892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.SfgPetClinicApplication.main(SfgPetClinicApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 47 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-02 22:27:38.143 ERROR 13892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.SfgPetClinicApplication.main(SfgPetClinicApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 47 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Spring has rather extensive and helpful error messages. Please add the entire error message (incl. stack trace) to your question.

Answer (score 6):

You are most likely running on JDK 11 or higher. One of the libraries you use is *javassist* (probably as a dependency of the Spring framework). Version 3.22 is not compatible with JDK 11 and causes the error.

Either upgrade to javassist 3.24 (by upgrading to the newest Spring Boot version 2.2.4.RELEASE which has a dependency to it) or downgrade to JDK 8.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

---

As a tip for investigating Java error logs:

1. Locate the **first** error. In your case it's: `2019-04-02 22:27:38.143 ERROR 13892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication  : Application run failed`
2. Follow the associated stack trace and go to the **innermost** exception, i.e.go the last `Caused by:` before the next error starts. In your case it's:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
```

That's the real cause that you want to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Codo :)
I have found the answer just a few minutes before you posted the comment.
It was a tricky problem for me. I have assumed that Null pointer Expception as caused by a missing getter/setter or missing Constructor.
But when I have analyzed the error I have located this line:

```
"Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister"
```

And a have made a reserach and find out that I need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency into my pom.xml file. 
And this problem is exactly what you have descibed above.

Thank you for your help and fast response :)
I have learned something new this day

Comment: Thanks Simon. Solution Perfectly working for me after adding this dependency.

Comment: You can upgrade to the newest Spring Boot version `2.2.4.RELEASE` which has dependency (transitively by `hibernate-core`) to newer `javassist` version `3.24.0-GA`.